# UITableViewCell with Checkmark not visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've a problem with my UITableView inside PopoverController.
When I touch cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function is called, and the cell accessoryType is changed. Example simplified :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

It's working, the cell are checked, but it's not visible on my tableview : I can't see the blue checkmark. However, in touch state on the cell, the checkmark is visible in white (and the cell background is gray). But not visible in default state.

Do you have any idea why my checkmark are not visible in default state ?

Thanks,

Edit: Add screenshot, for a cell with `accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`

[image]

Comment: for default state you have to put  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; inside - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method.

Comment: Yes I put it and it's working. My problem is on the display...

Comment: Now by default is working,and on display what is missing

Comment: Here : On the default state, the checkmark is not visible but the cell have nevertheless `accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. The checkmark are only visible when I touch the cell.

Comment: did you get this figured out?  I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me when I changed the global tint color to white. Once I realized, I went into the UITableView and change the tint color locally for just this table. Fixed.

Comment: This helped me solve my problem. If anyone else has this issue and wants to keep the global tint color set, just change the tint in viewDidLoad() in your TableView class:

self.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()

Answer (score 3):

I've tried the answer Jacky Boy - didn't help. But something was there in the deselection...

So I've tried to deselect the cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: before adding the checkmark accessory:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   UITableViewCell* selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   if (row != _selectedRow) {

       if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

          selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
          _selectedRow = row;

       } else if (selectedCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {

          selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       }
       [tableView reloadData];
   }
```

}

And for me it worked at last - the nice dark checkmark now is clearly visible on the cell!

Of course there is a part in cellForRowAtIndexPath: similar to described in arexx's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where, after reloading the row with a checkmark set as the accessory, the checkmark wouldn't be visible (but would be visible in white when the row was selected). In testing around the problem I discovered that the checkmark is always present in the cell, it's just white-on-white.

My understanding of the problem is that when I ask for the cell to be reloaded (so that I can show it with a checkmark), the existing cell is put on the reuse queue, but is at that time in a selected state (because the user just selected it). It's still in a selected state when the cell comes back off the reuse queue and you re-configure it in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath, and because it's selected, the accessory is set in white instead of in a visible colour.

To fix this, I added a line in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to force the cell not to be selected. The accessory is now always visible when the new cell is displayed.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get a reusable cell - this only works with Storyboard prototype cells 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    // THE MAGIC BIT
    // Force the cell to not be in a selected state.    
    cell.selected = NO;
    // END MAGIC BIT

    if (indexPathIsPathOfSelectedRow) {
         // This is the selected cell, so show the checkmark accessory.
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
         // In case we're reusing a cell that previously showed a checkmark, clear it.
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine was the most stupidest reason. I had created a tableview in storyboard, with a View Controller of size 5.5 inch and **forgot to apply the layout constraints**.

Then I launched in a 4 inch phone, Everything looked fine except the accessory view was not visible because of tableviews width was greater than that of the phone screen. It took me 3 hours to find out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are reloading the `UITableView` so in theory the cells are recreated and this time without the checkmark. Do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Fair enough, then you need to mark that specific cell somehow. So when the `UITableView`is reloaded the checkmark will still be there. You can keep a reference to the `indexPath` and in the `cellForRowAtIndex` you take care of checking.

Comment: It's not the problem, in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I verify and add the checkmark if necessary. My problem is on the display, not in the function.

Comment: Hummm, how do you create the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Running under iOS 6.1, the behavior I see is a cell with a white check mark on an almost white background. This appears to be happening because the code that draws the check mark accessory believes the cell is in a highlighted state, so rather than drawing the check mark in the normal blue color, it is drawn in white.

Setting the selected state of the cell did not work for me but setting the highlighted state immediately before setting the accessory type did. With the following in place, I always get a dark blue check mark.

```
cell.highlighted = NO;
if (checked)
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload Data then you should store selected Id in some variable for single selection like rowIndex and then in

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //check index
    if (rowIndex==indexPath.row)
        {cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIImageView *)checkmarkImg{
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_check_black_24dp.png"] changeColor:CLR_BUY];
    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    return  checkmark;
}

        cell.accessoryView = [self checkmarkImg];
```